# why are my css content boxes different sizes in firefox and internet explorer?

Tags: css, html

*EDIT / SOLVED* Found my own answer. For everyone that's wondering, it's:

```
DIV{-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

I have the following CSS code which I believe is pretty much "normal" and should therefor my interpreted by all browsers equally. The problem is that in Firefox the box is about 20 pixels wider than in Internet Explorer. What is the cause? How can I get them equally wide?

Here is the CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.commentbox{
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 200px;

border-top-color: #D1D1D1;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;

border-bottom-color: #D1D1D1;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;        

border-left-color: #D1D1D1;
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;

border-right-color: #D1D1D1;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;    


box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
padding-bottom: 9px;
padding-left: 9px;
padding-right: 9px;
padding-top: 9px;

position:relative;
display:block;
}

.title{
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
}

.count{
text-align:right;
}
</style>
```

And the HTML code:

```
<body bgcolor="#f3f3f3">
<div class="commentbox">
<div class="title">some long long long text that might take up two lines</div>
<div class="count">123</div>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vvAXu/)

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it might help if you also specify which version of IE you are using, since they pretty much show pages differently in every version.

Comment: Found my own answer! DIV{-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}

Comment: I don't see the difference with IE8 in the jsFiddle. Your original webpage doesn't use quirks mode, does it? There is an IE-only quirk with the box model. Also, with your workaround, you might want to test in other browsers too.

Comment: Post your own answer now

Answer (score 1):

Your Doctype, or lack of one, is causing browsers to render your page in Quirks Mode. In this mode they favour emulating the bugs of ancient browsers instead of following standards. There are many inconsistencies between browsers in Quirks mode.

One of the bugs, in Internet Explorer, is that it places `padding` inside the `width` of an element. The (new, draft, experimental) `box-sizing` property allows browsers to do that intentionally.

You should use a Doctype that triggers Standards mode to avoid inconsistances with standard code.

HTML 4.01 Strict is usually the best choice for a modern document.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

You might also consider the draft HTML 5:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ie do you see the differences with.  I am trying this with ie9 and they are the same for me.  I put it in a fiddle to see [myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/XNLCG/).

Try reading this and see if this explains what you are seeing.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Answer (score 0):

In case of CSS3 try to play with `box-sizing: content-box | border-box | inherit`
http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing